# How to restore missing workspace after windows update?

Tags: lotus-notes, workspace

Yesterday my office laptop has windows update. So I updated it. Then today, when I open my `Lotus Notes` my workspace has disappeared. Even on my left toolbar no workspace Icon. I try using a trick on this [Page](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21337549/Missing-Workspace-tab.html) but still nothing happened. My workspace becomes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMqeY.png) image.

Please anyone can help me to restore my workspace back? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this. I found the link [here](https://uwindsor.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=9399). So what I need to do based on the link are:

1. Close Lotus Notes
2. Launch windows explorer and find a file called bookmark.nsf. My file is on this link- C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data\
3. Replace bookmark.nsf to bookmark.old.nsf. (MAKE SURE TO CHANGE "NSF" FILE).
4. Then open Lotus Notes. Lotus Notes will now automatically recreate new bookmark.nsf from bookmark.ntf.
5. After finish, for my situation, I need to do an extra step to restore the workspace. I press ctrl + M to open Memo. Then on subject insert this command: @command([windowworkspace])
6. Then I open a bookmark, find workspace and click on my workspace. Done!

If you guys don't understand, please refer this [link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21337549/Missing-Workspace-tab.html) or this [link](https://uwindsor.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/KB/ArticleDet?ID=9399). Hope it helps others. Thank you!